# Reflection to generate SQL in C#?

Tags: c#, mysql, orm

I have my own ORM but i notice it preforms poorly when for example i get 100k results. For each iteration i reflect each type, its fields/properties and classes it uses (1 deep).

Reflecting a class 100k times get slow. Is there some kind of thing i can use to generate C# code so i dont need to use reflection? I could just rewrite the important select queries as regular sql instead of using my ORM but i thought i ask if there is a tool first.

I am using a mysql db.

-edit- Temp solution. dapper.net seems to have the performance i need on queries while my own orm creates tables, inserts and has addition execute features. Between the two i think i have EVERYTHING i need. (remember i need performance on selects which dapper offers, i dont need performance on inserts unless my site becomes huge)

Comment: You can emit a specialized class for each type you will consider, using the `System.Reflection.Emit` namespace.

Comment: why would you bother writing your own flawed (by your own stated reasoning) ORM, when there are so mnay tried and tested ones available? Rather than use reflection, try code generation...

Comment: @Mitch: This was about 2 years ago and i wrote it in a week. It does exactly what i needed (local computer, no performance requirements. extremely easy to use). Now i need something different.

Comment: @cdhowie: What do you mean? The problem is i am reflecting 100k times and its not really the fact of how slow reflection is or not. It just overhead i want to get rid of.

Comment: @Mitch: Funny enough Entity Framework looks harder to use then my ORM and if it does reflection every loop then it would have the same problems. (PS: My syntax is `var ls = conn.SelectAll<PoDType>("where !col=? AND !col2=?", a, b);` which i can write `func( ls.first().col.data)`. Pretty great but not performance friendly in large numbers)

Comment: @acidzombie24: I mean you can emit a class that handles each class, then use that class 100k times.  Since the emitted code will be JIT-compiled, you'll get the performance you want -- no reflection overhead except when compiling the initial class once.

Comment: @cdhowie: Oh nice! Well now the problem is writing that -_-. Maybe the Entity Framework does it for me? (But it doesnt look like it takes in PoD class). How might i store/execute the class? reflect the name 100k times. Check if it is in the dictionary/build if not then execute it? -edit- please tell me someone did this already. I thought of and implemented a limited version in a week 2 years ago!

Comment: Scary, dapper and my ORM are the same number of lines (well, within 10)

Comment: @acidzombie24 There are also other ORMs like [subsonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) which claim to be flexible... perhaps take a look of spring-boarding off those templates?

Comment: Nhibernate may be well worth looking into as well.  It can deal with PoD classes from what I recall.  (Or at least PoD classes derived from one of its own types.)  It emits code at runtime to optimize and avoid reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Dapper.NET](http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/) is great for selects and generates+compilers CLR code automatically to become really really fast.

Answer (score 2):

Myself, I'd use an existing ORM, but to answer the question, here's a simple example of setting a property via a dynamically generated setter:

```
void Main()
{
    var setter = GetPropertySetter<MyClass>("MyProperty");

    var myClass = new MyClass();
    setter(myClass, "This was set by the setter");
    Console.WriteLine(myClass.MyProperty);
}

Action<T, object> GetPropertySetter<T>(string propertyName) 
{
    var property = typeof(T).GetProperty(propertyName);
    var target = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var value = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
    var assignment = Expression.Assign(Expression.MakeMemberAccess(target, property), Expression.Convert(value, property.PropertyType));
    var propertyGetterExpression = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, object>>(assignment, target, value);
    return propertyGetterExpression.Compile();
}

class MyClass {
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

(Don't forget `using System.Linq.Expressions;`)

Comment: Good idea.  Note that this will have function-pointer overhead for each property.  If the OP wants to do the same sequence of things to each object of a particular class, it will be more efficient to compile a method for each class.  (This isn't a criticism of your answer, just another idea for whoever might read this.)

Comment: Also, it should be pointed out that each delegate should only be compiled once -- afterwards, one should reuse the previously-compiled delegate via some caching mechanism.  Creating a delegate for each access will be even more expensive than using reflection.

Comment: @cdhowie, both good points, but that last one especially required mentioning.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you use a cache to keep propertyInfo for each type.

Comment: You can, but the GetValue/SetValue calls are still quite expensive compared to a JIT-compiled property access.